# Changes Not Showing Client Side Without Clearing Cache

Tags: magento2, css, cache

Whenever I make changes **css** or anything I have to ask the client to **clear cache** to view the changes same for me.

Any advise on how to deal with this.

Magento 2.

Comment: remove `cache` and `page cache` folders from `var` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using versioning for `css` and `js`.

This option can be enabled in the:

```
`Stores` ->
    `Configuration` ->
        `Advanced` ->
           `Developer` ->
              `Static Files Settings` ->
                  `Sign Static Files` ->
                      `Yes`
```

This option adds a timestamp to js and css files and it allows to invalidate cache in the client's browser.

After enabling this option and flushing cache from admin panel or CLI, your files will look like:

```
domain.name/pub/static/version1511443406/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css
```

instead of

```
domain.name/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css
```

So the difference in the `version1511443406` part.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution but can be something helpful for you. The change which you are doing in your CSS, you will need to do the same change in `pub/...css` file. Because this is the file which actually gets rendered.

Not Sure if this will actually solve your problem, but will possibly be a way out to your issue.

Comment: but isnt the issue the client browser's cache? coz we are in production mode the static files should update I guess or I might be wrong.

Comment: The way to check that is to track if the client see your css changes in view source? And is the pub file getting deployed has your changes

Comment: aha ok will try to ask customers... I wonder how big companies handle that... there must be some kind of mod expiration on cache or something

Comment: You can check that in a different machine with different location